# Access Apache Oozie REST Services over Kerberos using python urllib2

Tags: hadoop, kerberos

i was planning to improve visualization details for an internal project using information provided by Oozie REST Services.

below is the python script to access oozie rest information

```
req=urllib2.Request('http://localhost:11000/oozie/v1/jobs?jobtype=wf')
response=urllib2.urlopen(req)
print json.dumps(json.loads(response.read()),indent=4,separators=(',',': '))
```

it works smoothly on non kerberos protected environment.

when script is run on kerberos protected environment, it results into

File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 518, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 401: Unauthorized

could anyone help on this issue.

Comment: **GOOGLE IS YOUR FRIEND** so just search for `python urllib2 kerberos` and, wow, you will see something about *"Kerberos over HTTP Negotiate/SPNEGO support for urllib2"*. Then it's just a matter of understanding how **SPNEGO** works and how to create a **Kerberos authentication ticket** (i.e. a TGT) before connecting.

Comment: And pleeeease remove the "oozie" tag and replace it with "hadoop" and "kerberos".